# Need to create rows out of a column in a specific way

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE STORE 
(
    STORE_CODE INT,
    STORE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    STORE_YTD_SALES NUMERIC,
    REGION_CODE INT,
    EMP_CODE INT
);

INSERT INTO STORE 
VALUES ('1', 'Access Junction', '1003455.76', '2', '8'),
       ('2', 'Database Corner', '1421987.39', '2', '12'), 
       ('3', 'Tuple Charge', '986783.22', '1', '7'),
       ('4', 'Attribute Alley', '944568.56', '2', '3'),
       ('5', 'Primary Key Point', '2930098.45', '1', '15');

CREATE TABLE REGION 
(
     REGION_CODE INT,
     REGION_DESCRIPT VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO REGION 
VALUES ('1', 'East'), ('2', 'West');
```

I am new to SQL I need to make a list of all stores and regions, as in the following sample:

```
Code        Description
----------- --------------------
1           Access Junction
1           East
2           Database Corner
```

but I am not sure how to make it work. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Which rdbms you are using?

Comment: SSMS (sql server management studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
SELECT Code, Description
FROM (
      SELECT STORE_CODE AS Code, Store_Name AS Description
      FROM Store
      UNION ALL
      SELECT REGION_CODE AS Code, REGION_DESCRIPT AS Description
      FROM REGION
     ) AS t
ORDER BY Code,Description
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Code    Description
---------------------------   
1       Access Junction
1       East
2       Database Corner
2       West
3       Tuple Charge
4       Attribute Alley
5       Primary Key Point
```

Link To the Demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6cc1a/2

Comment: @J.M try this and tell me is this what you are looking for.

Comment: May I ask you one more question, please?

Comment: Yes ask the question @J.M

Comment: Find the store codes that are in the employee table but not in the store table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f521/1
I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Since all store codes that are in employee table is also in store table, therefore, you are getting nothing as result. Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f521/6                                        
 And It's better if you can ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169298/discussion-between-j-m-and-nishant-gupta).

Comment: Okay. No Problem @J.M